# Removing Array Values From One Array By Comparing Keys Of Another Array

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose I have first array, $aAllCities as

```
Array
(
   [21] => London
   [9]  => Paris
   [17] => New York
   [3]  => Tokyo
   [25] => Shanghai
   [11] => Dubai
   [37] => Mumbai
)
```

And another array, $aNotSupportedCities as

```
Array
(
   [0] => 37
   [1] => 25
   [2] => 11
)
```

Is it possible to get an array like this ?

```
Array
(
   [21] => London
   [9]  => Paris
   [17] => New York
   [3]  => Tokyo
)
```

I want to remove array values of those keys that are present in other array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$aAllCities = array_flip( $aAllCities );
$aAllCities = array_diff( $aAllCities, $aNotSupportedCities );
$aAllCities = array_flip( $aAllCities );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Pushpesh, exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($aAllCities as $key => $value) {
    if(in_array($key,$aNotSupportedCities)) {
        unset($aAllCities[$key]); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct, but a smoother, faster way to do it is:
`$supportedCities = array_diff_key($aAllCities, $aNotSupportedCities);`

This will return all the values from `$aAllCities` that don't have keys in `$aNotSupportedCities`

Note, this compares the two arrays via their keys, so you will need to make your `$aNotSupportedCities` look like this:

```
Array
(
   [37] => something
   [25] => doesn't really matter
   [11] => It's not reading this
)
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
$supportedCities = array_diff_key($aAllCities, array_values($aNotSupportedCities));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$new = $aAllCities;
foreach($aNotSupportedCities as $id) {
  if (isset($new[$id]) {
    unset($new[$id]);
  }
}
```